# How to read all data into one line?

Tags: ruby

For example:

```
12 711
112 011 111 61 070 401 2216 515 
4 14 516 3
```

read as

```
127111120111116107040122165154145163?
```

Well I reading about STDIN but idk

Comment: What is your first line of digits? A string? A file?

Comment: Use `delete(str)' method
Example: -   str.delete('\s')

Comment: How do you read that data? Please show the corresponding code.

Answer (score 0):

```
"12 711 112 011 111 61 070 401 2216 515 4 14 516 3".delete("\s")
```

or

```
"12 711 112 011 111 61 070 401 2216 515 4 14 516 3".gsub(/\s/,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Read from standard input, then delete all newlines and whitespace.

```
STDIN.read.delete "\n\s"
```